# How to pass parameters to a .run file in linux

Tags: linux, automation, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have example.run file (binary file) that will install a simple software in my linux environment. I want to automate the installation with chef but the problem is that during the installation the software is asking to accept the license( so I have to type yes ) I want to see is there a way to pass a parameter with the .run file or chef can type the yes for me or etc.

```
file Talend-Installer-20150508_1414-V5.6.2-linux64.run
```

> Talend-Installer-20150508_1414-V5.6.2-linux64.run: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped

Comment: What is that `.run` file? The installer of AMD/ATI Catalyst? Or of NVIDIA driver?

Comment: It is a binary file.

Comment: Run `file /full/path/of/yourfile.run` and edit your question to show the result.

Comment: I just did it and post the result

Comment: I would rather ask such questions to Talend...

Comment: I did and I waited for like two weeks but no answer! I just want to see `yes | yourfile.run` is the only to run .run file with the parameters. Because I think this is the same any .run file!! Thank you

Comment: Also I have one more question! how about if I want to pass two args. for example the first one the answer is **yes** and the second one the answer should be **no**. I tried ` yes | no | file.run` but no result.
Thanks :)

Comment: I believe that you should have left the information that your `*.run` script is *Talend* related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the file (and there is no reason that every `*.run` installer behave similarly). Try `Talend-Installer-20150508_1414-V5.6.2-linux64-installer.run --help` or perhaps `Talend-Installer-20150508_1414-V5.6.2-linux64-installer.run -h` and read its documentation... sometimes there is an option to accept the license. You might also consider using [yes(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html) in a pipe:

```
yes | yourfile.run
```

But be cautious. What if `yourfile.run` asked politely:

```
can I remove every file in /home/ ? [yN]
```

<sup>(Of course, as for any script or executable, you'll need to enable executability and reading with `chmod u+rx` and either change your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) or use `./yourfile.run` or its absolute or relative file path, etc...)</sup>

You might also try to use [strings(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strings.1.html) on that executable, to perhaps guess (thru some string messages inside), what is possible.

Argument passing is done thru [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and your [*shell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) is in charge of [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) -before doing `execve`- so there is nothing specific about running `*.run` files.

I strongly suggest to take a few days to learn more about Linux. Perhaps read first [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) & [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) (and of course, [documentation of Chef](http://docs.chef.io/) and of the [Talend](https://www.talend.com/) product you are installing); if you experiment sysadmin things without understanding, you might mess your system to the point of losing data and having to reinstall everything. Both [echo(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/echo.1.html) & [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) might also be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your respond but unfortunately this didnt work. the .run is a binary file so I need to first make it executable by chmod +x command and then run ./myfile.run to execute it!

Comment: Yep, but that is unrelated to your question. For *any* script or executable, you need to make it executable and add it to your path.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I will definitely looking at these documentation :) unfortunately for me the `Talend-Installer-20150508_1414-V5.6.2-linux64-installer.run --help` and the `-h` didnt work it is saying that **Talend-Installer-20150508_1414-V5.6.2-linux64-installer.run: command not found**

Comment: You need to understand what `PATH` is. But really, you are lacking the minimal Linux knowledge and knowhow to be able to continue. Ask your boss to pay you some learning. You absolutely need to understand what is happening when you type something. blind-guessing is wrong!

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help. I am still in the college and this is my first internship :) but I will defiantly try to improve my linux knowledge. Again Thanks for all of your effort.